# Mail CLOB as ZIP into attachement using PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a CLOB datatype where I am hardcoding HTML code and then I want to ZIP it. Later send it as attachment.
Currently my code sends ZIP file as attachement but it doesnt open.

Note: Maybe need to convert CLOB into BLOB and then compress it & then send as attachment.

Can someone pls help me with a sample.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
    DECLARE
       p_from                                            VARCHAR2 (2000);
       p_to2                                              VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'xyz@abc.com';
       p_subject                                         VARCHAR2 (2000);
       p_smtp_host                                       VARCHAR2 (2000);
       p_smtp_port                                       NUMBER := 25;
       l_mail_conn                                       UTL_SMTP.connection;
       l_boundary                                        VARCHAR2 (50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
       atch_name                                    VARCHAR2 (50);
       atch_mine   VARCHAR2 (50) := 'application/zip';
       atch_clob   NCLOB;
       l_step          PLS_INTEGER := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
       dbname VARCHAR2 (50);
       hostname VARCHAR2 (50);

    BEGIN

    SELECT host into p_smtp_host FROM dba_network_acls where acl = '/sys/acls/utl_mail.xml' and rownum = 1;

    if p_smtp_host is not null then

    select host_name into hostname from v$instance;

    select name into dbname from v$database;

    p_from := dbname || '@' || hostname;
    p_subject := 'Test Mail';

       l_mail_conn                                              := UTL_SMTP.open_connection (p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
       UTL_SMTP.helo (l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
       UTL_SMTP.mail (l_mail_conn, p_from);
       UTL_SMTP.rcpt (l_mail_conn, p_To2);
       UTL_SMTP.open_data (l_mail_conn);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to2 || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn , 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf );
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    atch_clob := '<br><b><font size="2.5">Thanks,</font></b>';

    --  NAME   

    atch_name := 'test.zip';  

    -- ATTACHMENT 

      UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, ('--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf));
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, ('Content-Type: ' || atch_mine || '; name="' || atch_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf));
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || atch_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf));

UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, atch_clob);
       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);   

       UTL_SMTP.write_data (l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
       UTL_SMTP.close_data (l_mail_conn);
       UTL_SMTP.quit (l_mail_conn);      

    else
     dbms_output.put_line('Mailing Privilege not avaialble');
       END IF;
     END;
    /
```

Comment: [You might investigate the code at this link](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/as_zip8.txt). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing something in your code to get the data from lob, check the below code in which I am sending a pdf file as attachment from BLOB data type:

```
PROCEDURE Send_Email(ifrom In varchar2, ito In varchar2, icc In varchar2, ifile In varchar2, ifile2 In varchar2,
isubject In varchar2, imsg In varchar2, isrl_no In number)
 Is
 
    /*utl_smtp related variables. */
    vfile varchar2(100);
    v_connection_handle  Utl_Smtp.CONNECTION;
    v_from_email_address VARCHAR2(1000) := ifrom;
    v_to_email_address   VARCHAR2(1000) := ito;
    v_smtp_host          VARCHAR2(100) := 'mail.urdomain.com'; --your mail server
    v_subject            VARCHAR2(1000) := isubject;
    l_message            VARCHAR2(2000) := imsg;
  nls_charset    varchar2(255); 
    /* this send_header procedure is written in the documentation */
    PROCEDURE send_header(pi_name In VARCHAR2, pi_header In VARCHAR2) As
    BEGIN
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          pi_name || ': ' || pi_header || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    END;

 BEGIN
       Select Value
       Into   nls_charset
       From   NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
       Where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
 
    /*utl_smtp related coding. */
    v_connection_handle := Utl_Smtp.OPEN_CONNECTION(v_smtp_host, 25);
    Utl_Smtp.EHLO(v_connection_handle, v_smtp_host);
    utl_smtp.command(v_connection_handle, 'auth login');
  utl_smtp.command(v_connection_handle,utl_encode.text_encode('yourid@urdomain.com', nls_charset, 1));
  utl_smtp.command(v_connection_handle, utl_encode.text_encode('urpassword', nls_charset, 1));
    Utl_Smtp.Mail(v_connection_handle, v_from_email_address);
    Utl_Smtp.RCPT(v_connection_handle, v_to_email_address);
    IF icc Is Not Null Then
     Utl_Smtp.RCPT(v_connection_handle, icc);
    END IF;
    Utl_Smtp.OPEN_DATA(v_connection_handle);
    send_header('From', ifrom);
     send_header('To', ito);
    IF icc Is Not Null Then
      send_header('Cc', icc);
    END IF;
    send_header('Subject', v_subject);
    IF IFILE Is Null And IFILE2 Is Null Then
         Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                           'Content-Type: text/html;' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                            ' charset=US-ASCII' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, l_message || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    END IF;
   
    --mime header.
    IF ifile Is Not Null Then
     For i In 1..2 LOOP
      /*preparing the lob from file for attachment. */
          /*lob operation related varriables */
      IF i = 1 Then
        vfile := ifile;
      Else
       IF ifile2 Is Null Then
         EXIT;
       Else
        vfile := ifile2;
       END IF;
      END IF;
          DECLARE
         v_src_loc  BFILE := Bfilename('EMAIL_FILES', Nvl(vfile, 'temp'));
         l_buffer   RAW(54);
         l_amount   BINARY_INTEGER := 54;
         l_pos      INTEGER := 1;
         l_blob     BLOB := Empty_Blob;
         l_blob_len INTEGER;
         v_amount   INTEGER;
         BEGIN
      Dbms_Lob.OPEN(v_src_loc, Dbms_Lob.LOB_READONLY); --read the file
      Dbms_Lob.CREATETEMPORARY(l_blob, TRUE); --create temporary lob to store the file.
      v_amount := Dbms_Lob.GETLENGTH(v_src_loc); --amount to store.
      Dbms_Lob.LOADFROMFILE(l_blob, v_src_loc, v_amount); -- loading from file into temporary lob
      l_blob_len := Dbms_Lob.getlength(l_blob);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          'MIME-Version: 1.0' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          ' boundary= "' || 'EMAIL_FILES.SECBOUND' || '"' ||
                          Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      IF i = 1 Then
        -- mail body
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                            '--' || 'EMAIL_FILES.SECBOUND' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                            'Content-Type: text/html;' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                            ' charset=US-ASCII' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, l_message || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      END IF;
      -- mail attachment
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          '--' || 'EMAIL_FILES.SECBOUND' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' ||
                          Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          'Content-Disposition: attachment; ' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                         ' filename="' || vfile || '"' || --my filename
                          Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    /* writing the blol in chunks */
      WHILE l_pos < l_blob_len LOOP
        Dbms_Lob.Read(l_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
        Utl_Smtp.write_raw_data(v_connection_handle,
                                Utl_Encode.BASE64_ENCODE(l_buffer));
        Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
        l_buffer := Null;
        l_pos    := l_pos + l_amount;
      END LOOP;
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Dbms_Lob.FREETEMPORARY(l_blob);
     Dbms_Lob.FILECLOSE(v_src_loc);
      EXCEPTION
       When Others Then
         Dbms_Lob.FREETEMPORARY(l_blob);
         Dbms_Lob.FILECLOSE(v_src_loc);
        END;
     END LOOP;
      -- close email
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          '--' || 'EMAIL_FILES.SECBOUND' || '--' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      Utl_Smtp.WRITE_DATA(v_connection_handle,
                          Utl_Tcp.CRLF || '.' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
      END IF;
      Utl_Smtp.CLOSE_DATA(v_connection_handle);
      Utl_Smtp.QUIT(v_connection_handle);
  EXCEPTION
    When Others Then
--    utl_smtp.quit(v_connection_handle);
     IF ifile Is Not Null Then
      Utl_Smtp.QUIT(v_connection_handle);

     END IF;
      RAISE;
  END;
```

You can also check the following link to a blogpost I wrote, for full example:

[Sending emails with attachment in PLSQL](https://www.vinish.ai/oracle-utl_smtp-send-mail-with-attachment-example-using-oracle-wallet-authentication)

Comment: Hi Vinish, Thank you for the response. Actually i forgot to add CLOB fetch code line.. I have editted my original post. My question is to how to ZIP this CLOB and send as attachment.